# mysql 'case' with multiple 'WHEN' values

Tags: mysql, case

I have a a query that needs to do a count on a column where 2 other columns are true.
I need to Count 'DealerName' when 'DealerName' like '%MINI%' AND 'DealerContact_Y' = 1

But I am unsure of the syntax.  This query produces an error

```
SELECT DealerName,
       count(DealerShipId) as dealersContacted,
       CASE WHEN
       DealerName LIKE "%MINI%", WHEN DealerContact_Y = 1
       THEN Count(DealerContact_Y) END as Mini_contacted_yes,
       Campaign, 
       DealerId 
       FROM tblsummaryResults
```

IS there a way to do mutiple WHENS in a case statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would write it this way using `DealerName LIKE '%MINI%' AND DealerContact_Y = 1`:

```
SELECT DealerName,
  count(DealerShipId) as dealersContacted,
  count(CASE 
          WHEN DealerName LIKE '%MINI%' 
              AND DealerContact_Y = 1
          THEN DealerContact_Y END) as Mini_contacted_yes,
  Campaign, 
  DealerId 
FROM tblsummaryResults
```

Comment: thanks very much, this seems to be working, I will accept the answer as soon as the system allows.

Answer (score 1):

So, do the count like this:

```
COUNT(
  IF(DealerName LIKE "%MINI%" AND DealerContact_Y = 1, DealerContact_Y, NULL)
) AS Mini_contacted_yes
```